# Let $A=(A,\vee,\wedge)$ be a Boolean Algebra. So $\overline{x}=y$ is enough that...?

Tags: first-order-logic, boolean-algebra

> Let $A=(A,+,\cdot)=(A,\vee,\wedge)$ be a Boolean Algebra. To ensure that $\overline{x}=y$ is sufficient that:
>
> 1. $x+y=1_A$.
> 2. $x\cdot y=0_A\;\wedge\;x\neq0_A$.
> 3. $x\cdot(x+y)=\overline{y}\cdot x+\overline{(y+x)}$
> 4. None of the above.

---

I have some doubts.

## First question

First of all, **do we have to find $\text{??}$ in $\forall x,y\in A(\text{??}\to\overline{x}=y)$?**

## Second question

I think the correct answer is (3) because:
\begin{align*}
x\cdot(x+y)=\overline{y}\cdot x+\overline{(y+x)}&\implies x\wedge(x\vee y)=(\overline{y}\wedge x)\vee\overline{(y\vee x)}\\
&\implies x=(\overline{y}\wedge x)\vee(\overline{y}\wedge\overline{x})\\
&\implies x=\overline{y}\wedge(x\vee\overline{x})\\
&\implies x=\overline{y}\wedge1_A=\overline{y}\\
&\implies\overline{x}=\overline{\overline{y}}\implies\boxed{\overline{x}=y}
\end{align*}

**but I am not sure if I also have to discard the other possibilites (because we could find 2,3,... sufficient conditions, not only 1).**

## Third question

**Can you help me finding counterexamples for (1), (2) and (4)?**

For example for (1) I said $(D_6,\mid)$ where $D_6=\text{Divisors of $6$}=\{1,2,3,6\}$, which is a Boolean Algebra, and its Hasse diagram is:

[image: Hasse diagram]

but $\forall x,y\in A(x\vee y=1_A\to\overline{x}=y)$ is false. Indeed, take $x=2$ and $y=6$. Then $2\vee6=6$ but $\overline{2}=3\neq6$.

**What about (2) and (4) (if my counterexample is correct)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is right.

As for counter-examples for (1) and (2), and then (4) will follow, consider the three-element Boolean algebra.

For example, $(D_{30},|)$.
Here, $12\vee 15=30$, which is the top, but $12\wedge15=3$ which is not the bottom, and so (1) is not sufficient.
Check that also $2\wedge3$ is the bottom, but $2\vee3$ is not the top, so that $2$ is not the complement of $3$; so (2) is not sufficient either.